# Batch File Replace Extracted File

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd, unzip

I have a .bat file that unzips a kml from a kmz. If I run the batch file again it prompts me if I want to replace the file. Is there away I can have it always replace the file without prompting the user or displaying a cmd window?

```
    @echo off
    md tempKml
    cd tempKml
    ..\unzip ..\%1 >nul 
    cd ..
    dir tempKml\*.kml /s/b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the -o option?

```
..\unzip -o ..\%1 >nul
```

Comment: Which unzip utility are you using?  Type 'unzip' or 'unzip -h' or 'unzip -?'